# Inner Cursor In MySQL Server

Tags: mysql, relational-database, database-cursor

I am trying to use an inner cursor structure in MySQL server. To do that, I wrote the code below:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE example_proc()
BEGIN
    Declare a int;
    DECLARE done INT DEFAULT FALSE;
    DECLARE done2 INT DEFAULT FALSE;
    Declare b int;
    DECLARE cursor_i CURSOR FOR

        select 1;

  DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET done = TRUE;        
  OPEN cursor_i;
  read_loop: LOOP
    FETCH cursor_i INTO a;

        DECLARE cursor_j CURSOR FOR
            select 2;
        DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET done2 = TRUE;        
        OPEN cursor_j;
        read_loop2: LOOP
        FETCH cursor_j INTO b;

    end loop;
    close cursor_j;

  END LOOP;
  CLOSE cursor_i;
END;
```

But I had a syntax error at this line `DECLARE cursor_j CURSOR FOR`
. It says `Syntax error: missing 'SEMICOLON'`. I could not understand what is wrong here. So where am I doing wrong?

Comment: Cursor declarations have to be at the beginning of the procedure, you can't have it in the middle.

Comment: @Barmar So there is no way to use 2 two cursor within one procedure?

Comment: Of course you can. You just have to declare them all at the beginning.